# React useTable hook with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-table, react-table-v7

So I have a JavaScript class with useTable.
In Java script its been used like below

```
import {useTable, useFilters,useAsyncDebounce,useSortBy,usePagination,} from "react-table";

const {getTableProps,getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, page,prepareRow,state,visibleColumns, nextPage,pageOptions,pageCount,previousPage,canPreviousPage,canNextPage,setPageSize,gotoPage
      } = useTable({columns,data,defaultColumn,filterTypes,initialState: { pageSize: 10, pageIndex: 0 }
       },useFilters, useSortBy,usePagination);
```

I'm converting my javascript project to typescript.

In typescript that `useTable` line gives errors.

Example : `Property 'page' does not exist on type 'TableInstance<object>'.ts(2339)`

[image]

That `initialState` attribute gives my below error

```
Type '{ pageSize: number; pageIndex: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<TableState<object>>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pageSize' does not exist in type 'Partial<TableState<object>>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(172, 5): The expected type comes from property 'initialState' which is declared here on type 'TableOptions<object>'
```

How to write that `useTable` line in Typescript ?

Answer (score 15):

To use the react-table plugin extensions like `usePagination` with typescript the types for the plugins need to be declared.

This is done by creating a `react-table-config.d.ts` or similar and declaring the types for the plugin you'll be using (or for all of them).

This is described here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table

Comment: Would be great if they were added to `"@types/react-table"`

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it:

```js
import {
  TableInstance,
  usePagination,
  UsePaginationInstanceProps,
  UsePaginationState,
  useSortBy,
  UseSortByInstanceProps,
  useTable,
} from "react-table";

export type TableInstanceWithHooks<T extends object> = TableInstance<T> &
  UsePaginationInstanceProps<T> &
  UseSortByInstanceProps<T> & {
    state: UsePaginationState<T>;
  };

export const TableComponent = () => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0, sortBy },
    },
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  ) as TableInstanceWithHooks<Deal>;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You fixed a very bad day at the office.

Comment: Could you explain the Deal that is used `as  TableInstanceWithHooks<Deal>;`.How is it initialized ?

Comment: Deal is just the type of the data I am adding to the table, it could be any map type really `interface Deal { … }`