# How to use react-table useSortBy in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-table

I've searched everywhere but I can't find a clean way to use `useSortBy` hook with typescript.

```js
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    headerGroups,
  } = useTable({ columns, data }, useSortBy);

  return (
    <Table {...getTableProps()}>
      <TableHead>
        {headerGroups.map(hg => (
          <TableRow {...hg.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {hg.headers.map(column => (
              <TableCell {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                {column.render('Header')}
                  {column.isSorted
                    ? column.isSortedDesc
                      ? "D"
                      : "U"
                  : null
                }
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableHead>
    // ...
```

I'm getting TS errors because `getSortByToggleProps` doesn't exist on `column` neither `isSorted` neither `isSortedDesc`.

I've also tried adding `UseSortByHooks` with `useTable` but no luck:
`useTable<UseSortByHooks<MyData>>(...)`

Comment: Do you mean to have `column.getSortByToggleProps()` as a parameter to `column.getHeaderProps`?  Not familiar with the API, but that looks odd.  Also, you get `columns` but don't use it.

Comment: `columns` is a parameter of `useTable` method. The issue is that getSortByToggleProps doesn't exist on column, and i'm wondering if anyone else using TS has encountered this

Comment: Ok, but you aren’t using `columns`, and a deriving `column` from `hg.headers`.  Are you sure that’s correct?

Comment: I don't understand, `columns` is an argument of `useTable` wdym i'm not using them?

Comment: My mistake, was misreading it. I checked some other examples and you seem to be getting columns from the right place

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66681335/2902063), you need to create a declaration file when using plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the interface HeaderGroup in global types index.d.ts. Added UseSortByColumnProps

```
export interface HeaderGroup<D extends object = {}> extends ColumnInstance<D>, UseTableHeaderGroupProps<D>, UseSortByColumnProps<D> {}
```

This helped me.